# how destroy entry widget after get the value from user

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a program to create a entry widget after pressing particular "mode" button ,then taken inputs from user and want to destroy that entry widget after user pressed "enter" button.
I am new to python ,so unable to understand the error .
please help to find problem on my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("User Interface Monitor")
rpm=tk.StringVar(root)
tim=tk.StringVar(root)
def  enter():
    global rpm,tim
    root.rpmLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter rpm value:").grid(row=0)
    root.timeLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter time in sec").grid(row=1)
    root.e1 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=rpm).grid(row=0,column=1)
    root.e2 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=tim).grid(row=1,column=1)
    #rpm=rpm.get()
    #tim=tim.get()
    #return rpm,tim
def gett():
    global rpm, tim
    rpm = rpm.get()
    tim = tim.get()
    print(rpm)
    print(tim)
    root.e1.destroy()
    root.e2.destroy()
    #e1.pack()
    #e2.pack()
root.Button1=tk.Button(root,text="MODE1",command=enter)
root.Button1.pack()
root.Button1.place(x=200,y=200)
root.Button2=tk.Button(root,text="Enter",command=gett)#root.Button2.pack()
root.Button2.place(x=260,y=200)
root.mainloop()
```

it is my code.
i successfully taken inputs from user and given to my main program but fail to destroy the entry widget.
here my errors

```
11
2
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/RAM/PycharmProjects/timing/rpm.py", line 23, in gett
    root.e1.destroy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is in this lines

```
root.e1 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=rpm).grid(row=0,column=1)
root.e2 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=tim).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

The grid method returns None so after you are calling the destroy method on a variable that has inside the value `None`.

Instead you want to assign the entry to a variable and after grid it.

```
root.e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=rpm)
root.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tim)
root.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

As this it works.

Comment: Glad that it helped

Comment: Can you please help me how take value again from user as when i press same mode button again entry widget pop up but not taken value again@Mat.C